# Hibernate: model multiple tables with similar structure using one class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have two tables with the same structure:

```
Table1: 
tab_id
field1
field2


Table2:
id
tab_id
field1
field2
```

I want to create one class to model these two tables for example:

```
@Id tabId
@Column(name="field1") field1
@Column(name="field2") field2
```

Then do things like read from one table, change something and write to the other table:

```
myObject = find in Table1 ...
change myObject ...
save myObject to Table2 ...
```

Any idea how I should do this?

My best guess is use MappedSuperclass, but I'll have to include in each subclass Entity a constructor that takes the parent MappedSuperclass and copies every field...

---

Edit - I guess I can do this:

```
@MappedSuperclass 
@Data
class MySuper {
  MySuper(MySuper other) {
    // copy...
  }
  @Id tabId;
  @Column(name="field1") field1;
  @Column(name="field2") field2;
}    

@Table(name="Table1", ...) 
Table1Entity extends MySuper {
    TableEntity(MySuper other) {
        super(other);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use`MappedSuperclass`. To copy fields org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils  `copyProperties(Object dest,  Object orig)` would be hepful

Comment: Example code you have written using @MappedSuperclass 
  looks good for this purpose.